# Unix Bash AIX - Find files from one directory but not in another

Tags: bash, shell, unix, csv, bin

I have the following command so far, just a little stuck on the next bit.

```
comm -23 <( find /dir1/report_dir2/dir3/2013* -name *\*MyFile* -exec basename {} \; | sort | uniq ) <( find /dir0/dir1/dir2/loadedreports/archive* -name *\*MyFile* -exec basename {} \; | sort | uniq ) > /home/Ben10/list.txt
```

**Directory 1**

The files in `/dir1/report_dir2/dir3/2013*` are csv files that may or may not have a `.gz` extension in their name, unzipping them would be out of the question as they're up to a gig each, and i've thousands of them.

i.e they'll look like `MyFile20130618073529.csv` or `MyFile20130618073529.csv.gz`

**Directory 2**

The files in `/dir0/dir1/dir2/loadedreports/archive*` have been loaded to a BI system, and will all end in .csv,

however, they will also be preceeded by dates of when they were loaded,

i.e. `2013-11-06_MyFile20130618073529.csv`

I'm loading them into a BI DB from these csv files, and to check which ones i've loaded I need to check which ones are in `/dir1/report_dir2/dir3/2013*` but not in `dir0/dir1/dir2/loadedreports/archive*`

is there any way to disregard the `.gz`, and the `2013-11-06_` ? note, the 2013-11-06_ can be any date preceeding MyFile.

Thanks a million, any input greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

```
comm -23 <( find /dir1/report_dir2/dir3/2013* -name '*MyFile*' | perl -pe 's/.*(MyFile[^.]*\.csv)(\.gz)?$/$1/' | sort -u ) <( find /dir0/dir1/dir2/loadedreports/archive* -name '*MyFile*' | perl -pe 's/.*(MyFile[^.]*\.csv)$/$1/' | sort -u ) > /home/Ben10/list.txt
```

Here idea is to use `perl` search and replace, in place of `basename`, on found full file names to get desired basenames discarding `.gz` suffix and `<date>_` prefix

---

To make above one liner more readable, I would prefer splitting it as follows

```
find /dir1/report_dir2/dir3/2013* -name '*MyFile*' | perl -pe 's/.*(MyFile[^.]*\.csv)(\.gz)?$/$1/' | sort -u > /home/Ben10/di1_list.txt

find /dir0/dir1/dir2/loadedreports/archive* -name '*MyFile*' | perl -pe 's/.*(MyFile[^.]*\.csv)$/$1/' | sort -u > /home/Ben10/di2_list.txt

comm -23 /home/Ben10/di1_list.txt /home/Ben10/di2_list.txt > /home/Ben10/list.txt

rm /home/Ben10/di1_list.txt /home/Ben10/di2_list.txt
```

Comment: I split up the long statement and made each part a job, it came out remarkable like yours, thank you so so much.